# Can Visual Studio 2017 be set to only auto-format leading whitespace?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, code-formatting

Are there any solutions (settings or otherwise) for forcing Visual Studio to only auto-format the leading whitespace of a line and nothing after that? This would be mainly in Visual C# or Visual C++ projects.

As a deliberately contrived example, I'd like code like this:

```
     namespace Foo
{
    public static class Bar
        {
private static int a                = 1;
        public  static int some_very_long_b = 2;
    public  static double Derp(double value)
    {
    if      (value < a               ) return 0;
       else if (a     > some_very_long_b) return 1;
     return value;
}
}
}
```

to be auto-formatted to this:

```
namespace Foo
{
    public static class Bar
    {
        private static int a                = 1;
        public  static int some_very_long_b = 2;

        public  static double Derp(double value)
        {
            if      (value < a               ) return 0;
            else if (a     > some_very_long_b) return 1;
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Note specifically how, while the scopes were correctly indented, any spacing after the initial leading white-space of a line was left untouched.

A different way of wording this problem would be: can I prevent auto-format from messing with in-line whitespace when it's more than what the auto-format settings dictate?

I'm fine with `a+b` being turned into `a + b` if the `Formatting > Spacing > Set spacing for operators > Insert space before and after binary operators` setting is enabled, but would like some way so that `a    + b` would not have its extra whitespace removed.

---

I've looked in `Options > Text Editor > C# > CodeStyle > Formatting`, and I'm fairly certain that the options there don't provide such a feature. Is there anything I'm missing?

*Edit: I've added an [issue for this on the dotnet roslyn github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/28536).*

Comment: Fair, I've removed references to 3rd party tools from the question.

Comment: I don't see anything in VS options to specify formatting leading whitespace only.  If it formats, it formats everything as configured.  The only options I see are for automatic formatting (i.e. things that trigger formatting other than an explicit command).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look upon [editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/), Visual Studio have nice [integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options) with it. Not only formatting but you can also encode some language specific coding styles powered by Roslyn.

Answer (score -2):

Just press Ctrl+E, Ctrl+D for code formatting

Comment: -1, appears to have not actually read the question. This violates my requirement of "Note specifically how, while the scopes were correctly indented, any spacing after the initial leading white-space of a line was left untouched."